# Linux serial port woes

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am writing code to talk to another device over serial in linux

I want non-blocking with timeout even if 0 characters arrive. The termios struct allows you to set VTIME and VMIN, but if VMIN is larger than 0, and if 0 characters are returned, the read call will block forever...WTF, why. This does not seem to cover the case where the other device goes down for a short period of time and now my application is blocked on a read call. This seems like a critical behavior to neglect. I really do not want to implement my own timeouts.

```
Write command
Read block timeout of around .3s(if 0 characters, still wait max of .3s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `select`.  It waits until data is ready to read (but doesn't actually read anything).  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

> *timeout* is an upper bound on the amount of time elapsed before **select()**
>   returns. It may be zero, causing **select()** to return immediately. (This is 
>   useful for polling.) If *timeout* is NULL (no timeout), **select()** can block 
>   indefinitely.

The code would look something like:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 300000;

fd_set infds;
FD_ZERO(&infds);
FD_SET(fd, &infds);

// Assume fd is the file descriptor for the serial device
if (select(fd + 1, &infds, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
{
    // The read will not block now
    // Assume buffer and size are declared and set appropriately
    amountRead = read(fd, buffer, size);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that serial ports are select() able?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `read` to return with no data after a timeout you can set `MIN == 0` and `TIME > 0`. From `tcsetattr(3)`:

> MIN == 0; TIME > 0: TIME specifies the limit for a timer in tenths of
>   a  second.   The  timer  is  started when read(2) is called. read(2)
>   returns either when at least one byte of data is available, or  when
>   the  timer  expires.  If the timer expires without any input becoming
>   available, read(2) returns 0.

This mode can be used to build higher level communication functions which you must implement anyway in order to deal with partial reads (i.e. if the other end crashes in the middle of a "packet"), wrong packets, split packets and so on. That's all stuff which a simple `read` cannot do for you.